# Solve the recursion nT(n) = (n − 2)T(n − 1) + 2

Tags: recursion, math

I have tried recursion-tree but failed. I also could not solve the problem using math skills...and the Master theorem also seemed unavailable.

Comment: Can you explain more certain what do you want?

Comment: Emmm I want to know the asymptotic time complexity of T(n).

Comment: I guess it's theta ( logn ) , but i can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If we only define `T(1)` then we always have `T(2) = 1` regardless of what `T(1)` is. So the answer is `T(n) = 1` it comes from the fact that if `T(n-1) = 1` then `T(n) = [(n-2) * 1 + 2]/n = 1`.

So let us suppose `T` starts from `2` rather than `1`. Consider multiple scenarios :

1. **T(2) > 1** : Then for `n>2` we have `T(n) < T(n - 1)`, also `T(n) > 1` so limit `T(n) = 1` :

   because if `T(n-1) > 1` then `T(n) = [(n-2) * T(n-1) + 2]/n` we have : `T(n-1) > 1` so `[(n-2) * T(n-1) + 2]/n > n/n = 1`. Also `(n-2) * T(n) + 2 T(n) = (n-2) T(n-1) + 2` and we have `T(n) > 1` so : `(n-2) * (T(n) - T(n-1)) = 2 * (1 - T(n)) < 0` so `T(n) - T(n-1) < 0` so `T(n) < T(n-1)`.

   You have to prove there are no boundaries other than `1`.
2. **T(2) < 1** (including negatives) : Using a similar approach to the one mentioned above(not exact) you could argue that for `n>2` we have `T(n) > T(n-1)` and `T(n) < 1`. And again prove that limit `T(n) = 1`.
3. **T(2) = 1** : As I mentioned above if `T(2) = 1` then `T(n) = 1`.

PS: I didn't provide a complete solution because it seems to be homework. I hope you can figure out the rest.